# Eines or Einer in this context

Tags: article, gender, indefinite-pronoun

Which form of ein words is correct in the following context?

W201 war ...... der Besten von Mercedes.
einer?
eines?

I think here eines is the correct form because the singular form of Besten (Das Beste) is a neuter word.
However, I'm not sure of my answer because it could refer to Mercedes which is a masculine noun (Der Mercedes).

My second question is:
What is the difference between *ein* and *einer* when both are singular masculine in nominative case? What about *ein* and *eines* when both are singular neuter in nominative case?

Comment: May I ask, that you stop creating new tags on the fly? Non-consented tags are useless for categorization and so only clutter the system (until removed).

Comment: Wer oder was ist denn W201? Ein Modell, eine Person, eine kaufmännische Zeiteinheit, ...? Ah, gefunden, ein Automodell. Dann muss es aber heißen "Der W201 war einer der Besten von Mercedes.", mit dem bestimmten Artikel vorneweg. Der Artikel von "Mercedes" ist unerheblich, da sich das Abstraktionsniveau (die Limousine, der Wagen, das Auto, der PKW, das Fahrzeug, das Produkt, ...) nicht implizit ergibt. Bei "war einer der besten Mercedesse" wäre es anders.

Comment: @user unknown - Meinen Sie, dass " einer " auf W201 sich bezieht? (weder das Beste noch der Mercedes)

Comment: -Das ist leider nicht eindeutig, außer dass es sich nicht auf Mercedes beziehen kann. Ich habe keine Ahnung von PKWs, kannte nur S- und A-Klasse als Begriffe. Es müsste vorher eigentlich gesagt worden sein, wovon die Rede ist, von 4-Taktern, PKWs generell, W-ler (gab es da auch einen W200 oder W101?), etc.. "Der W201 war einer/eine/eines der besten PKWs/Limousinen/Modelle von Mercedes". Bei einer Antwort auf "Sprechen wir von 4-Taktern; wie gut war der W201?"/"Der W201 war einer der Besten von Mercedes." geht dann, ohne "4-Takter" zu wiederholen.

Comment: Als Autoignorant hielt ich W201 beim ersten Lesen für  bezogen auf eine ökonomische Kennzahl wie "KW7/2023 war (vom Umsatz) eine der Besten für Mercedes". Es bezieht sich also auf einen der Besten Xe, wobei wir nicht wissen, was X ist, und folglich welches Geschlecht X hat und ob es also einer, eine oder eines ist.

Comment: @user unknown - Alle Mercedes Modelle haben Baureihen Codes (W201, W124, W126). W201 steht für die erste C-Klasse Generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second question first:

"Einer", "eines", "eins" are pronouns. They stand in for a noun.

> Der Juli ist einer der heißesten Monate. *(... one of the hottest months.)*
> Gibst du mir noch einen *(akkusative)* von den Keksen? *(... one of the cookies)*
> Eins wollte ich dir schon immer mal sagen: Du bist super! *(One thing I always wanted to tell you")*

"Ein" is an indefinite article, it's used *together with* a noun.

> Ein Mercedes ist ein Auto. *(A Mercedes is a car)*

Question 1:

The gender of the pronoun is defined by the gender of the noun it stands for. In this case it is part of the construction "eine[r|s] der Besten", so its gender needs to be whatever the gender of "die Besten" is. Which is ambiguous.

It would be easy if it said "der besten Autos" - Auto is sächlich (neutral), so it would be "eines der besten Autos". Or, with "Wagen": "einer der besten Wagen".

In this sentence though, you can't tell, so you can use either "eines" or "eins" if you e.g. think of "Autos" or "Modelle", or you can use "einer" if you e.g. think of "Wagen" or "Mercedes".

What actually **doesn't** play a role here is the gender of "W201" (which is male, because for some reason actual car models almost always are: der Käfer, der 230 D, der 911, der Corolla).

> Charlotte ist eines der besten Mädchen in der Klasse. *(because it's "das Mädchen")*
> Die "Gorch Fock" ist einer der bekanntesten Traditionssegler unter deutscher Flagge. *(der Traditionssegler: traditional sailing ship)*

> (Der) W201 war eins der Besten von Mercedes.

It's still not great style, because it's still not entirely clear what basic set "der Besten" refers to. The best of what? Coupés? Autos? Fahrzeuge? It would make the sentence clearer if it defined that.

> (Der) W201 war eines der besten Modelle von Mercedes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The only question that remains is when should I use eins and when eines?

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian You can use either, there is no difference in meaning. "Eines" is a little bit more formal than "eins".

Comment: This answer is wrong. You would never, ever, ever say „Charlotte ist eins unserer Besten“ (because you're secretly thinking „Mädchen“), and for the same reason you cannot say „Der W201 war eins der Besten von Mercedes“ (because you're secretly thinking „Autos“). It *would* work if the noun was uttered before or after, e.g. „Wir haben viele Mädchen, Charlotte ist eins unserer besten“ or „Charlotte ist das beste, aber wir haben noch andere Mädchen“ etc. But minus this context, no way.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel "W201 war einer der Besten von Mercedes." is just as good or bad in every respect as "W201 war eins der Besten von Mercedes.". That's what I tried to point out in the last paragraph. and that's still my opinion on this matter. As for fhe Charlotte example - ok, I can see how the actual gender would be dominant over an unspoken category here.